# (Ruby:Gosu) Gosu drawing shape images with sprites

Tags: ruby, libgosu

i am making a simple game using Gosu, however i do not want to use external sprites for my game and i would rather draw images using code, is it possible to use code drawn images as if they were external images.

Note: i only want to draw basic shapes, such as squares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use draw_line, draw_triangle, draw_quad methods of Window class for it.